# Do we need a small displacement to create a oscillatory motion on the spring?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, spring, oscillators, vibrations

Do we need a small displacement to create a oscillatory motion on the spring with a mass attached to it? Whats the limit of the displacement that we can give initally to create a oscillatory motion? Is it has to be small or it can large?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an ideal spring the force as a function of position is $F=-kx$. Since this is a restoring force for all $x$, there is no limit on what initial displacement will cause oscillations (anything will do).

Even if your spring is not ideal, the force will probably have the form of $F=-f(x)$, where $f(x)>0$ for all $x\neq0$,  so that the force is still restorative. Therefore you would still have oscillations for all displacements from equilibrium.

Where this breaks down is in the real world your springs can't stretch forever. Even assuming perfect elasticity, your spring wouldn't be able to stretch past it's full stretched out length. For real springs, there is a point where if you stretch the spring past it, the spring will not restore to its original form. Unfortunately, this depends on the physical spring itself, so at this point I can't keep talking in general.

Comment: What about if we say we need to satisfy the energy conservation or simple harmonic motion. Is that changes something ?

Comment: @ArthurMorgan If you want Simple Harmonic Motion, then your force has to be of the form $F=-kx$. If you want to force to be conservative then you need to be able to find a potential energy function $U=-\int F\ \text{d}x$, which I think for 1D just means your force cannot explicitly depend on the velocity.

Comment: I mean that,  to satisfy the simple harmonic motion or energy conservation do we need small x ? Or its again does not depend how much you strech it.

Comment: @ArthurMorgan It really depends on the specifics of the spring and how much you want to consider (ideal or not). For example, if you are stretching your spring out farther then you will lose more energy due to heat of stretching the spring. If you deform the spring by stretching it too far, then your force will probably not have the form $F=-kx$, and so you will no longer have SHM.

Answer (score 1):

The displacement sets the initial amplitude of the oscillations, which will go down from that point. So, the greater the displacement, the greater the amplitude.

The only limit here is the sterchability of the spring.